# Scraping Google captcha "I am not a robot" enabled website with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I was going through a blog that said, if a website uses google recaptcha "I am not a robot" then its not possible to scrape those website even with tools like selenium.
But when I started reading about how google recaptcha actualy works, I learnt that it tracks the movement of the mouse

> The way a human moves the mouse before checking the checkbox can be
>   distinct from how a program (a bot) checks a checkbox. It's a game of
>   prediction. Somehow, Google needs to predict whether you are human or
>   a bot from what you do on their site.

So my question is there are currently many tools available in python with which you can move your mouse pointer pixel by pixel. Lets say our captcha was found at (100,100) and our pointer is currently at (200,250). Then we can make movement such using tool in this sequence. what I mean is having few ms difference between the movements.
(200,250)->(199,249)->(198,248) ..... and ultimately after some zig zag movement to (100, 100).

Answer (score 1):

Selenium already gives you the option to [move your mouse by some offset](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=mouse#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset).

That being said, Captcha are here for a reason, and that is to stop people using bots on their sites. That means they have to deal with harsher attacks by professionals and most likely have some defense against this quite simple try of defeating Recaptcha.

Comment: ok then in what other way can recaptcha detect that it was a robot

Comment: If that information was public, people could just write scripts to get around it. Recaptcha is made to **stop** bots, as soon as people know how to stop that detection, it would seize to be a security measure.

[Here](https://youtu.be/o1zNIm8GVPY) is an educatonal video for beginners.